# Two different graph ticks parameters on Y axes from one table

Tags: python, matplotlib

Considering below table:

| country | points | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| England | 91.550725 | 51.681159 |
| India | 90.222222 | 13.333333 |
| Austria | 90.190782 | 30.762772 |
| Germany | 89.836321 | 42.257547 |
| Canada | 89.377953 | 35.712598 |

```
d = {'points': [91.5, 90.2, 90.1, 89.8, 89.3], 
'price': [51.6, 13.3,30.7, 42.2, 35.7]}
index=['England', 'India','Austria', 'Germany','Canada']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index,data=d)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
color = 'tab:purple'
ax1.set_xlabel('Country', fontsize=12)
ax1.set_ylabel('Average Ratings', color=color, fontsize=12)
sns.barplot(x=df['points'],y=df.index, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color, labelsize = 12)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  
plt.xlim(12, 92)

color = 'tab:red'
ax2.set_ylabel('Price', color=color, fontsize=12)  
sns.barplot(x=df['price'],y=df.index,color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color, labelsize = 12)
```

[image]

My question: How can I modify the right side Y axis ticks parameters to **price** (red), so that it represents the numbers of **price** column as well as the title.

- Pandas: 1.2.4
- Seaborn: 0.11.1
- Matplotlib: 3.3.4

Comment: Have you tried to adapt the examples provided in the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html)? There are several examples with multiple axis labels.

Comment: Yes I have extensively looked at those but unfortunately haven't figured out how to modify mine, hence decided to ask for help.

Comment: Fair enough. However, when trying your code in the question, the output is not even close to the image shown. Please share the code that you used to create the image.

Comment: I wonder why. I have just double checked and run several times. It is identical and the same outcome is reproduced.

Comment: [This is](https://imgur.com/Qne3sGM) what I get. Maybe for a start, you create the pandas dataframe within your question to exclude the possibility that differences in the dataframe are the problem. You should also include the matplotlib, seaborn, and pandas versions you use.

Comment: @Mr. T, I have applied as requested. I hope this will help further. Thanks

Comment: Okay, now I can reproduce your output. People always underestimate that differently constructed pandas dataframes can look the same when printed out. And your problem is now, that on the right side, `51.6` should be shown instead of `England` and so on?

Comment: @ Mr. T, Yes, I learned a new valid point, thanks. This way the title also correctly changed from “country” to “price” on the right side. So one step forward and I don’t know how it affected it. Yes, as you stated I would like the values replace the country names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this comes close to what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

d = {'points': [91.5, 90.2, 90.1, 89.8, 89.3], 
'price': [51.6, 13.3,30.7, 42.2, 35.7]}
index=['England', 'India','Austria', 'Germany','Canada']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index,data=d)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
color = 'tab:purple'
#ax1.set_xlabel('Country', fontsize=12) <-- not necessary for your output
ax1.set_ylabel('Average country rating (in points)', color=color, fontsize=12) #mention unit for rating
sns.barplot(x=df['points'],y=df.index, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color, labelsize = 12)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
plt.xlim(12, 92)

color = 'tab:red'
ax2.set_ylabel('Price (in $)', color=color, fontsize=12)  #mention unit for price
sns.barplot(x=df['price'],y=df.index,color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color, labelsize = 12) 
ax2.set_yticklabels(df['price']) #relabel right axis with price values
ax1.set_xlabel("") #remove x-label because this axis applies to both categories

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

However, I hope you take the point into account that Trenton mentioned in a comment (now deleted). This graph is indeed rather difficult to read. The values on the left have their labels on the right, and vice versa.

Comment: It is certainly understood and is a fair point. Though, it helped me to experimentally apply such changes and learn new tips. I also took Trenton point into account but his focus was not my need. Appreciate your effort, thanks a lot.